# Best way/place to ask frequently asked questions

Tags: discussion

A lot of my questions are programming related. So if I have a question about how to convert an integer into a string in javascript, I ask it on StackOverflow. If I have a question about how to efficiently run x number of virtual servers in apache2 I ask it on ServerFault.

Then often times I find I my questions border on FAQs, like if I ask for help on why my `suPHP` module is not working with my Apache daemon.

Then there are times when questions I ask are definitely FAQs. Like if I can't install a, for example, SVN server, and ask for help (and hope I get detailed help).

What is Stack Exchange's views on FAQ type questions? Are they encouraged or discouraged? Personally I would prefer to have one format for FAQs here, rather than going to several different tutorial sites, and using information from numerous discussion forums.

Comment: You ask a lot. Do you search beforehand at all?

Comment: @random depends. First I search for it on Stack Exchange. If it isn't there then I google it. If I don't find an answer, I ask a question here. The exception is when I would have to do a lot of set up (ie. download and configure `suPHP` and create multiple users and build a website to run `PHP` scripts...) before finding out that the question to my 'can I do this...' question is 'NO'

Answer (score 3):

If it's actually a frequently asked question, I bet it would already be asked somewhere on Stack Exchange.

SVN server installation questions would probably land on Server Fault or Stack Overflow. suPHP interacting with Apache seems like something for Stack Overflow of Webmasters.

Other than that... I'm honestly not sure what you mean by "FAQs". A question is a question. Basic/beginner questions are typically allowed, with a few exceptions on sites that are specifically targeting more complex issues like, for example, [Theoretical Computer Science](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/) which only accepts research-level CS questions.

The only thing to keep in mind is that you should do some research on your own first to see if anyone (on Stack Exchange or otherwise) has already encountered and solved your problem.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044221/does-apache2-support-virtual-hosting-of-subdomains) of a question that I asked and answered. It's a comprehensive answer aimed at newbies. I was wondering if Stack Overflow would frown on this as being more like a tutorial. In other words, I could have titled the questions 'Can someone give me step by step instructions how to do this'

Comment: @puk Ah, I see. Are you asking if self-answering questions in a tutorial-like format is okay? It is. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to) for more details.

Comment: well not self answering in particular, but yes. Also requesting it.